# jQuery, Dynamic on | accessing dynamic targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

How to access the dynamic targets when using `jQuery.fn.on` with dynamic selectors?

Because `$(this)` is giving the parent element inside binder function.
And I need to get each element itself to fetch corresponding `data-attributes` dynamically.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/u1kuufj7/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="1" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="2" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="3" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="4" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="5" class="ch">Click</div><br>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var $container = $('#container');
var $chs = $('.ch');

$container.on('click', $chs, function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: What is the issue actually?

Comment: $(this) inside binder function is giving the parent element and not the child on which the event is actually bound. I need the children inside bind function.

Comment: Note: These days, Stack Snippets (the `<>` button) should be preferred to jsFiddle as they're on-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use event delegation, the second argument to [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) should be a *selector* (a string), not a jQuery object:

```
var $container = $('#container');
var $chs = '.ch';                   // <== Changed

$container.on('click', $chs, function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Now, `this` will refer to the `.ch` that was clicked.

**Live Example:**

```js
var $container = $('#container');
var $chs = '.ch';

$container.on('click', $chs, function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="1" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="2" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="3" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="4" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="5" class="ch">Click</div><br>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: `$(this).attr("id")` is just a long way to write `this.id`.

Side note 2: While `id` values starting with digits are perfectly valid, they're awkward to work with in CSS, since ID selectors can't start with a literal digit. (There are ways around it, via escaping or via attribute selectors, but it's awkward.) For that reason, I usually avoid `id`s starting with digits.

Comment: Example was just for mirroring the actual functionality :-P . Obviously NO `$(this).attr("id")` and Neither *numberic ids* . That I just copy pasted and changed to few attributes

Answer (score 1):

Use, you're passing a jQuery object to `.on()`

```js
var $container = $('#container');
$container.on('click', '.ch', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="1" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="2" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="3" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="4" class="ch">Click</div><br>
  <div id="5" class="ch">Click</div><br>
</div>
```